# what is concept of warping layer in PWC-Net neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, opticalflow

i am researcher of AI and i am studying below paper about PWC-Net convolutional neural network, but i dont understand "Warping layer" section in this paper and i am confused about this.
[image: PWC-Net]

please explain me "Warping layer" section in simpler words or introduce me some references about this layer.
thanks a lot.